# Need a SQL query to use result from first query

Tags: sql, join, nested, db2

I have a table t1 that has fields(columns) aa,bb,cc unique combination set provides matches one isk in the same table so each record can be identified in t1 either using the combination of aa,bb,cc or by simply using isk

and I have another tablet2 which has only aa, bb, cc but has another column(field) as spo which is not in t1

So, I need to get

```
Select spo
from t2
where aa= t1.aa and bb= t1.bb and
       cc= t1.cc in (select aa,bb,cc from t1 where isk = <User Input>)
```

but this query is not working

Kindly provide a query to get the expected results

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT spo
  FROM t2 INNER JOIN t1 ON t2.aa= t1.aa and t2.bb= t1.bb and t2.cc= t1.cc
 WHERE t1.isk = <User Input>
```

Comment: How to do update using inner join for the above sample query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuples in expressions like :

```
Select spo
from t2
where (aa, bb, cc) in (select aa,bb,cc from t1 where isk = <User Input>)
```